# How to get text from input field without submiting form in php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, button, fill

I am using this code

```
$('.calc').blur(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.calc').each(function() {
        if($(this).val()!="")
         {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
         }

    });
        $('.full_calc').val(sum);
});
```

to fill dynamically input and I want to get its data dynamically (changed in every new input filled) in php variable and use it for other calculations without a submit button.   Can I do this?

Comment: you wnat to submit it on chnage or you want do it without refreshing page?

Comment: Provide a more detailed explanation of the problem as well as  the html structure used. It's not clear if the code shown is actually working properly or what you are expecting

Comment: so you want to recursively retrieve every input value with an on blur event and create a new php variable each time and store the value in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, change jquery file name like you have there :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>On Change</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        function sum(){
            $("#n3").val(eval($("#n1").val())+eval($("#n2").val()));
        }
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#n1").change(function(){
                sum();
            });
            $("#n2").change(function(){
                sum();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    N1 :<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" value="0" /><br>
    N2 :<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2" value="0" /><br>
    N3 :<input type="text" name="n3" id="n3" value="0" />
</body>
</html>
```